# ogr.geometry() and ogr.GetGeometryRef() differences

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

Can you tell me the difference between ogr methods ogr.geometry() and ogr.GetGeometryRef()? Is there any difference in returned object in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that [ogr.geometry()](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html#ac0b82162f8efdec26efee2e22aba8cda) is the constructor of a geometry, while [ogr.GetGeometryRef()](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRFeature.html#acc966ce8c10ae3ddf9f14c2736fdce9a) fetch the pointer to a feature geometry. The objects they return are respectively an [OGRGeometry](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRGeometry.html) and an [OGRFeature](http://www.gdal.org/classOGRFeature.html).